# vuejs antdesign popover max width

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, antd, ant-design-pro

Unable to set maxWidth on popover element from ant design for vuejs.
I've tried:

```
<a-popover 
    placement="rightTop" 
    trigger="hover" 
    overlayStyle="{maxWidth: 123px}"
>
```

failing with:

```
runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?2725:169 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Indexed property setter is not supported.
```